# How to remove/ignore quotation before JSON { and ] in Java

Tags: java, json, escaping, quote

```
String param = "{\"a\":\"[\\\"x\\\",\\\"y\\\"]\",\"b\":\"{\\\"z\\\":1}\"}";
```

In my case, {...} and [...] are quoted by ". JSON treats it as a String integrally.

```
{
    "a": "[\"x\",\"y\"]",
    "b": "{\"z\":1}"
}
```

How can I **remove OR ignore** the quotation around {} and []? The result I want is:

```
{
    "a": [
        "x",
        "y"
    ],
    "b": {
        "z": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are those blocks quoted? The two JSONs are very different (the first one contains strings, the second one contains lists and mappings of strings), maybe it's easier to act on the source of the JSON. Do you have control on the source?

Comment: Another thing you can do: if you know that "a" and "b" contain strings like those... you could extract those strings and parse them again as separate JSONs

Comment: I know what you say, but I get the data from a third part and Can't change it. Moreover, "a" "b" is just an simple example, the real path is not sure, and the data usually nested deeply. If only there is a parser i can custom that treats the "{...}" or "[.....]" as List and Map.

Answer (score 0):

The safest solution is to use a JSON parser to parse and re-serialize each value. Here's an example using Jackson:

```
String param = "{\"a\":\"[\\\"x\\\",\\\"y\\\"]\",\"b\":\"{\\\"z\\\":1}\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode root = mapper.readValue(param, ObjectNode.class);
root.set("a", mapper.readTree(root.get("a").asText()));
root.set("b", mapper.readTree(root.get("b").asText()));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(root));
```

Output:

```
{"a":["x","y"],"b":{"z":1}}
```

Comment: the example is simple, "a" and "b" is not SURE, the actual data is nested deeply.

Comment: @waterystone Then it's impossible to solve correctly, since there's nothing to differentiate actual JSON from a string containing JSON. Unless you want to treat any potential JSON as actual JSON.